# Number of Tabs I do get after striking Tab key in Vim Insert mode

Tags: c, vim, configuration, vi, auto-indent

I am learning C programming.

I met a problem about vim configuration.

The following is my vim setting written in .vimrc:

```
set nu
set shiftwidth=4
set tabstop=4
set softtabstop=8
set autoindent
set cindent
set smartindent
syntax on
```

In order to see where the tabs are, I have used `:set list`:

```
#include <stdio.h>$
int main(void)$
{$
^Iprintf("ab\n");$
^Ireturn 0;$ 
}$
```

Now in line 4 under Insert mode, I want to see how many tabs I can get after I strike Tab key in different locations.

Here's the result:

When I strike <kbd>Tab</kbd> after `n`, I get `^Iprin^I^Itf("ab\n");$`.

When I strike <kbd>Tab</kbd> after `\n`, I get `^Iprintf("ab\n^I^I");$`.

The above two situations are quite understandable to me.

But when I strike <kbd>Tab</kbd> after `a`, I get `^Iprintf("a^Ib\n");$`.

This is beyond my understanding.

Can anybody explain why there is only one tab replaced?

I thought there should be two because `softtabstop` takes up 8 spaces which is two times `tabstop` (4).

Comment: tab does not always have the same length. tab always indents to a position which is a multiply on your tabstop. So if your tabstop is 4 the tab will stop at 4,8,12,16...
This means if you insert a tabstop at position 3, it will be only of length 1 (3->4). But if you insert it on position 5 it will be of length 3 (5->8)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the result of the interaction between your `softtabstop` and (regular) `tabstop`.

Your `softtabstop` says when hitting the Tab key, the results should be aligned with multiples of 8 columns. When you strike Tab after a, you're already at column 13, so just one 4-width tab character is enough to get there. In the other cases you were at 16 and 8, respectively, so it took two 4-width tab characters to align to your 8-width soft tab.

PS: if you want weird behaviours (not recommended of course), set `tabstop=3 softtabstop=8`. Then you get combinations of spaces and tab characters when you hit the Tab key.

PPS: All this is part of why I don't like literal Tab characters. They're unstable, their display depending on each developer's tab-stop settings. In my organization, I push hard for everyone to use `:set expandtab` (or the equivalent in each developer's editor) and use space characters for stable and reproducible display. The only place I tolerate tab characters in my work is in makefiles, where I don't have a choice.